Why are the buttons and entries in this example customtkinter code invisible?
When I run the code, the window appears and I can hover over the button and click it. The button's functionality works; when my cursor is over where the button is supposed to be I can click it, the only problem is that I can't see it.
here's the code:
import customtkinter

customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("dark")
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("dark-blue")

root = customtkinter.CTk()
root.geometry("500x350")

frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=root)
frame.pack(pady=20, padx=60, fill="both", expand=True)

label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=frame, text="Login System", font=("Roboto", 24))
label.pack(pady=12, padx=10)

entry1 = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=frame, placeholder_text="Username")
entry1.pack(pady=12, padx=10)

entry2 = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=frame, placeholder_text="Password", show="*")
entry2.pack(pady=12, padx=10)


def login():
    print("Login test")


button = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=frame, text="Login", command=login)
button.pack(pady=12, padx=10)

checkbox = customtkinter.CTkCheckBox(master=frame, text="Remember Me")
checkbox.pack(pady=12, padx=10)

root.mainloop()

Clicking the invisible button works and prints "Login test", but again, the UI is just a blank rectangle:
The resulting ui
I already ran pip install --upgrade customtkinter and it didn't help. Not sure if that would have done anything in the first place, but that was pretty much the only solution i could find online.

What os, python version and customtkinter version are you running ? It works just fine for me (I use windows, python 3.12 and customtkinter 5.2.1).

Are you using macOS?

Yes, I’m on macOS.

code works correctly also on Linux. Did you tried with other themes?

I tried the same code with light theme and it still didn't work. Python 3.12.3, customtkinter 5.2.2.
